# Deploy AddIn-part(s) only to sp online

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to deploy one or more addin-parts (not just addins). Provider hosted.

I have no problems deploying a provider hosted addin, and no problem adding a addin-part to the existing addin. In VS I create an SP Addin-project and right-click on the SP-project and then Add new "client web part". But when I deploy SP asks me if I trust  (which is ok). I can see the default MS addin which I never use. It also creates an QuickLaunch-entry to this useless default addin

BUT: 
I just want to deploy the addin-part(s) without any addin... hope this is somewhat clear :D

Answer (score 1):

From where I understand, you have a provider hosted add-in and you want to deploy only the Add-in without the web? If yes, then please follow the below steps

1. In the solution on the web project, right click and select unload project
2. Go to the App Manifest file of the Add-in, inside the tag App Principal, where it says RemotePrincipal, change the tag to 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Murtuza! Im not on that project right now, but I will test your solution as soon as I am.

Comment: Hope it helped! Feel free to add light here!